# Show number of ListTile according to a condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to develop an app about five books all with different number of chapters e.g

1. Book A - 20 chapters
2. Book B - 14 chapters
3. Book C - 23 chapters
4. Book D - 18 chapters
5. Book E - 19 chapters

> I have done **:**
>
> > `the signIn page` the `the signUp page` and the `the choose book page`
>
> I want to do **:**
>
> > `the choose chapter page`

NOTE: BOTH `the choose book page` AND `the choose chapter page` USE LISTTILE

When it came to the choose chapter page i had a problem with displaying the number of ListTiles according to book type, should i create different choose chapter pages for each book **(i was afraid of repetition of code)** or there is a feature in Flutter that lets you show number of ListTiles according to certain condition **(if its available)** the condition in my case being the book type

I need a guide to whether i should **:**

1. Create different choose chapter pages for each book.
2. Use a feature in Flutter that lets you update ListTiles according to certain condition.

In the `the choose book page` one of the `ListTile`

CODE I TRIED SO FAR

```
ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/books/book_a.jpg"),
          ),
          title: Text(
            'Book A',
          ),
          subtitle: Text('2348033980943')
          onTap: ()
          {
            //can i define no.ofchapters here and take the value on to the next screen??
            int number_of_chapters = 20,
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChooseChapterScreen.id);
          },
        ),`
```

Comment: You could create a `ChapterList` widget that builds the list of `ListTile`s in a `Column` or `ListView`. Pass in the book as a property and use the number of chapters as the number of `ListTile`s to create.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Chapters{
   String title;
   List<String> chapters;

   Chapters(this.title,this.chapters);
}

              // Inside your tap method
              onTap: ()
              {
                List<String> chaptersList= ["Chapter 1", "Chapter 2", "Chapter 3"];
                // you can pass arguments with named routes
                Navigator.pushNamed
                       (context, 
                       **Your_Next_Screen**,
                       arguments: Chapters(                               
                       'Book A',                              
                       chaptersList,       
                       ),                                                                                                                 
                );
              },
```

Inside your build method of the **Your_Next_Screen** retrieve the data like,

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute settings and cast
    // them as Chapters.
    final Chapters args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    var title= args.title;
    var list= args.chapters;

    return Scaffold(
      // your widget
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ListView.builder()`([Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html)) for that. It takes some parameters, like the number of items you want to build, and a builder method to be called for each of the N elements you wish to build.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: book.chapters.length, // Use the number of chapters here
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    // Each chapter will be a ListTile, you can add more parameters, or use whatever widget
    return ListTile(title: Text("Chapter $index"));
  }
)
```

[Here's an example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists) by the Flutter team.

Comment: `itemCount: book.chapters.length, // Use the number of chapters here`  bearing in mind the choose book page has listtile too can i define number of chapters in each listtile of each book?

Comment: i added the code in my question  so that you can see